# Autoit won't send Enter to close Excel file

Tags: excel, autoit, vba

[image]I have an autoit script that opens an excel workbook , modifies it , saves as csv and exits, except I can't get it to exit. It locks on the last save confirmation screen prior to closing, I have added a photo of the window it stops working on. Here is my script.

```
    [![#include <Excel.au3>
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>

; Create application object
Local $oAppl = _Excel_Open()
If @error Then Exit MsgBox(16, "Excel UDF: _Excel_BookOpen Example", "Error creating the Excel application object." & @CRLF & "@error = " & @error & ", @extended = " & @extended)

; *****************************************************************************
; Open an existing workbook and return its object identifier.
; *****************************************************************************
Local $sWorkbook = @ScriptDir & "\Abacus List.xlsx"
Local $oWorkbook = _Excel_BookOpen($oAppl, $sWorkbook, Default, Default, True)
If @error Then Exit MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "Excel UDF: _Excel_BookOpen Example 1", "Error opening '" & $sWorkbook & "'." & @CRLF & "@error = " & @error & ", @extended = " & @extended)

Sleep(2000)
Sleep(2000)
Sleep(2000)
Send("{ENTER}")
Send("{ALTDOWN}{F11}{ALTUP}")
Send("{ALTDOWN}{I}{ALTUP}")
Send("{M}")
Sleep(2000)
Send("Sub sbVBS_To_delete_firstFewRows_in_Excel() {ENTER} Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete {ENTER} Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete {ENTER} Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete {ENTER} Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete {ENTER} Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete {ENTER} Columns(\[1\]).EntireColumn.Delete {ENTER} Columns(\[1\]).EntireColumn.Delete")
Send ("{F5}")
Sleep(2000)
Sleep(2000)
Sleep(2000)
Sleep(2000)
Send ("{ALTDOWN}{F4}{ALTUP}")
Sleep(2000)
Sleep(2000)
Sleep(2000)
Send("{F12}")
Sleep(2000)
Sleep(2000)
Sleep(2000)
Sleep(2000)
Send("{TAB}c{ENTER}")
Sleep(2000)
Sleep(2000)
Send("{TAB}{ENTER}")
Sleep(2000)
Sleep(2000)
Send("{ENTER}")
Sleep(2000)
Sleep(2000)
Sleep(2000)
_Excel_BookClose($oWorkbook, False)
Send("{TAB}{ENTER}")
Sleep(2000)
Sleep(2000)
Send ("{ALTDOWN}{F4}{ALTUP}")][1]][1]
```

Comment: Why don't you just `Send("!s")` to send **ALT + S** to push the Save button? Look here for some more examples: https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/appendix/SendKeys.htm

Comment: I tried that, as well as other options, it's as though autoit can't or won't send anything to that window and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

If you really run out of options just kick on the location.

WARNING: this can resoult a lot of bugs and errors, when you for example change the screen resoloution.

You can detect the position of the button with "AutoIt Window Info" and then click with:

```
MouseClick("left", $pos1, $pos2)
```

It's a really cheap solution but if it works it works! ;D

Answer (score 0):

Try `ControlClick` or `ControlSend`. Use AutoIt Info Tool to get the handle of the message box.